# phrase request: complexity of interpersonal relationships

Tags: word-requests, phrase-request

This has been harder to find than I imagined.

I'm looking for any sort of phrase or quote that talks about how, very, complex interpersonal relationships are.

The best I've found so far is something like:

人情似纸张张薄，世事如棋局局新

which is okay, but I was wondering if there was anything better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common phrase for 'complex' is **錯綜複雜**

It can be used to describe:

1. Relational complexity

> Example: 人際關係錯綜複雜 (interpersonal relationships are complex)
>
> Example: 兩人的關係錯綜複雜 (the relationship between the two men are complicated)

2. Logical complexity

> Example: 案情錯綜複雜 (the case is complicated)

3. Physical complexity

> Example: 江南河道錯綜複雜 (Jiangnan's River system is complicated)

Another common phrase for 'complex' is '**千絲萬縷**' (tangled/complicated)

> Example: 兩人的關係千絲萬縷 (the relationship between the two men are complicatedly tangled)

One more phrase related to the question: '**人心隔肚皮** '

It means everyone has their own agenda. No one really knows exactly what other people are thinking.

*Chinese sayings like '满肚密圈', '心知肚明' suggested people keep their intentions and plans in their '肚' (belly)* which is always inside a person and hidden from views.

Answer (score 1):

人人关系扑朔迷离

《乐府诗集·横吹曲辞五·木兰诗》：“雄兔脚扑朔，雌兔眼迷离，双兔傍地走，安能辨我是雄雌。”